# Powerline rendering in EMACS

Tags: term

The rendering of `term` command in emacs runs my `zsh` shell but doesn't render it properly. Can anyone direct me to a fix?[image]

This is how it should look:
[image]

Comment: What does `powerline` have to do with this?  What are we looking at?  What does "doesn't render it properly" mean specifically? What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: What @phils said. Define "*properly*". Specify what you think is improper. The question is unclear, so far, so it risks being deleted as unclear.

Comment: Random guess: You haven't customized Emacs to use a patched powerline-specific font. This can be checked with `M-x describe-char` with point on the prompt.

Comment: Sorry for improperly describing my problem. My concern is the extra spaces that appear when `zsh` is running inside Emacs.